# Bash script only functioning on certain inputs

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a bash script that I've been working on for a while. Basically, it searches through text to find repetitions of multiple lines. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

count() {
    count=$(( $3 - $2 + 1 ))
    pattern=$(echo  "$1" | head -n $3 | tail -n $count)
    echo "$1" | pcregrep -Mc "^\Q$(echo "$pattern")\E$"
}

file=$1
fileprep=$(grep -v '=' $file | grep -v '!' | grep -v '*' |  grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | grep . )
linecount=$(echo "$fileprep" | wc -l)
len=10
start=1
end=$(( $linecount - $len + 1 ))



for i in $(seq $start $end); do
    test="$test\n$(count "$fileprep" $i $((i+len-1)))"
done

a=$(printf $test | grep -v '\b1\b' )

mostrepetitions=$(echo "$a" | sort -rn | head -n1)

for i in $(seq 1 $mostrepetitions); do
    var1=$(printf "$a" | grep '\b'$i'\b' | wc -l)
    var2="$var2\n$(echo $(( var1 / i )))"
done

printf "$var2" | tr '\n' '+' | awk '{print "0"$0}' | bc -l
```

I have found that this works correctly on a simple file that has the numbers 1-10 repeated twice (like so):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

On this, it will correctly output 1 (with the `len` variable at 10). When the `len` variable is changed to 9, it will correctly output two, because both 1-9 and 2-10 are 9 line patterns that occur at least twice.

However, when I run this on my target files (an example of which can be found [here](http://kern.humdrum.org/cgi-bin/ksdata?l=users/craig/classical/bach/violin&file=partita1-2.krn&f=kern)), I get impossible results.

In this script, the amount of nine-line patterns found will always have to be at least double the amount of ten line patterns. Take the above example of 1-10. In that, 1-10 is the only ten line pattern. However, within it are both 1-9 and 2-10, both of which are repeated twice. When I run my script though, for ten-line repeated patterns, I get an output of 2, and for nine-line patterns I also get an output of 2. This is clearly incorrect. Why is this happening?

Note - the `fileprep` variable was created to create a list of numbers from the input file (see the sample file I linked).

Comment: Some comments in the code would help to understand what the idea behind the various parts are, and what they *should* do.

Comment: What's tho overall purpose? To find cycles? Or to do a sort of a frequency analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomenon you describe is actually not impossible, so your script is not the problem. The smallest example I can think of is with `len=3` as opposed to `len=2`, and the input file is

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

With `len=3`, you get the result `2`, but with `len=2`, you don't get some number `≥4` as you would maybe suspect, but again the result `2`. In order to get the same number of distinct repeating patterns with `len=10` as well as with `len=9`, you just need to extrapolate the file to 13 lines.

#### Addendum:

I modified the `count()` function to

```
count() {
    count=$(( $3 - $2 + 1 ))
    pattern=$(echo  "$1" | head -n $3 | tail -n $count)
    occur=$(echo "$1" | pcregrep -Mc "^\Q$(echo "$pattern")\E$")
    [ $occur -ge 2 ] && echo "$pattern occurs $occur times." >&2
    echo $occur
}
```

So it prints the pattern which repeats to the standard error output. It says that the 10-line pattern

```
16
...
16
```

appears 360 times, while the 10-line pattern

```
16
...
16
8
```

appears twice. On the other hand, the 9-line pattern

```
16
...
16
```

appears 362 times, while

```
16
...
16
8
```

appears twice. Your file contains many blocks of subsequent lines with `16`. What puzzles me is why the 9 lines with `16` do not occur once more for each such block, but only two times more than the 10 lines in total.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had never thought about the fact that there are more distinct 10 line possibilities than 9 line.